# proving the equation has at least one at least one real solution

Tags: calculus

> If $g(x)=3^x+2x^{\frac{1}{2}}$. Then prove that the equation $g'(x)=21$ has at least one real roots

What i try:: given $g(x)=3^{x}+2x^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Then $\displaystyle g'(x)=3^x\ln(3)+2\cdot \frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}=3^x\ln(3)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$

Now i did not understand How do i find number of solution of $g'(x)=21$

Help me please , thanks

Comment: You could even prove that there are two solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g'$ is continuous at $(0,+\infty)$.

$$g'(1)=3\ln(3)+1<21$$

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}g'(x)=+\infty$$

thus there exist $ b>1$ such that $g'(b)>21$.

$21\in (g'(1),g'(b)) $ so, By EVT, $$\exists c\in (1,b) \; : g'(c)=21$$

Remark:

$g' $ is a derivative, we do not need its continuity.

Comment: @Moo I mean Darboux theorem : Extreme Value Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: rearrange ${g'(x)=21}$ as ${\ln(3)3^x + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-21=0}$ and try to use the intermediate value theorem